# Android beacon library compilation issues

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ibeacon

I'm trying to make the Android Beacon Library work for a project but I'm facing a few issues.

I downloaded the library, added it to eclipse and then imported the sample project (https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference). Everything was working fine on Linux mint so I developped my own service based on this library.

Then I shared my code with some friends who encountered some issues on windows. Indeed, eclipse wasn't showing any errors but the apps were crashing (sample app and my own app).

So I tried to import the project on windows too and the app was crashing too. We tried this on multiple computers. I don't really understand where the errors come from. Here are the logcats :

Sample Project :

```
11-28 22:23:17.089: D/AndroidRuntime(7145): Shutting down VM
11-28 22:23:17.089: W/dalvikvm(7145): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41569ba8)
11-28 22:23:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(7145): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-28 22:23:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(7145): Process: org.altbeacon.beaconreference, PID: 7145
11-28 22:23:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(7145): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application org.altbeacon.beaconreference.BeaconReferenceApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.altbeacon.beaconreference.BeaconReferenceApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.altbeacon.beaconreference-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.altbeacon.beaconreference-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
11-28 22:23:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(7145):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:516)
11-28 22:23:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(7145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4317)
11-28 22:23:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(7145):     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method)
11-28 22:23:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(7145):     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:631)
11-28 22:23:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(7145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(Native Method)
11-28 22:23:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(7145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-28 22:23:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(7145):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
11-28 22:23:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(7145):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-28 22:23:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(7145):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-28 22:23:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(7145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
11-28 22:23:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(7145):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-28 22:23:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(7145):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-28 22:23:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(7145):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
11-28 22:23:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(7145):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
11-28 22:23:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(7145):     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
11-28 22:23:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(7145):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-28 22:23:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(7145): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.altbeacon.beaconreference.BeaconReferenceApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.altbeacon.beaconreference-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.altbeacon.beaconreference-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
11-28 22:23:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(7145):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
11-28 22:23:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(7145):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
11-28 22:23:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(7145):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
11-28 22:23:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(7145):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:975)
11-28 22:23:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(7145):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:511)
11-28 22:23:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(7145):     ... 15 more
```

Own Project :

```
11-28 22:29:05.230: I/dalvikvm(8591): Failed resolving Lcom/eirb/projets9/scanner/RangingService; interface 772 'Lorg/altbeacon/beacon/BeaconConsumer;'
11-28 22:29:05.230: W/dalvikvm(8591): Link of class 'Lcom/eirb/projets9/scanner/RangingService;' failed
11-28 22:29:05.230: E/dalvikvm(8591): Could not find class 'com.eirb.projets9.scanner.RangingService', referenced from method com.eirb.projets9.MainActivity.onCreate
11-28 22:29:05.230: W/dalvikvm(8591): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 673 (Lcom/eirb/projets9/scanner/RangingService;) in Lcom/eirb/projets9/MainActivity;
11-28 22:29:05.230: D/dalvikvm(8591): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x000f
11-28 22:29:05.280: D/AndroidRuntime(8591): Shutting down VM
11-28 22:29:05.280: W/dalvikvm(8591): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41569ba8)
11-28 22:29:05.280: E/AndroidRuntime(8591): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-28 22:29:05.280: E/AndroidRuntime(8591): Process: com.eirb.projets9, PID: 8591
11-28 22:29:05.280: E/AndroidRuntime(8591): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.eirb.projets9.scanner.RangingService
11-28 22:29:05.280: E/AndroidRuntime(8591):     at com.eirb.projets9.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:56)
11-28 22:29:05.280: E/AndroidRuntime(8591):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
11-28 22:29:05.280: E/AndroidRuntime(8591):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-28 22:29:05.280: E/AndroidRuntime(8591):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
11-28 22:29:05.280: E/AndroidRuntime(8591):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
11-28 22:29:05.280: E/AndroidRuntime(8591):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-28 22:29:05.280: E/AndroidRuntime(8591):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
11-28 22:29:05.280: E/AndroidRuntime(8591):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-28 22:29:05.280: E/AndroidRuntime(8591):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-28 22:29:05.280: E/AndroidRuntime(8591):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
11-28 22:29:05.280: E/AndroidRuntime(8591):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-28 22:29:05.280: E/AndroidRuntime(8591):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-28 22:29:05.280: E/AndroidRuntime(8591):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
11-28 22:29:05.280: E/AndroidRuntime(8591):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
11-28 22:29:05.280: E/AndroidRuntime(8591):     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
11-28 22:29:05.280: E/AndroidRuntime(8591):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

As I said the app is running well when compiled from linux. I tried to modify the order of imports.

Do you have any idea where do these errors come from ?

Comment: What versions of Eclipse and Java are you using for compilation on Windows?  What versions of Eclipse and Java are you using on Linux?

Comment: Eclipse juno with the last version of the ADT plugin on both.
On windows I'm using java 6. I have to check on Linux.
But while I was typing this answer, it seems that I solved the problem by downloading the latest versions of :
- Android SDK Platform-tools
- Android SDK Build-tools
- the Android API 21 and 20.

I have no idea why it fixed my issues but everything seems to be working fine now.

Comment: Glad to hear you found the issue!  Will you please post your solution as an answer and accept it for the sake of others facing the same problem?  It would be great to post the problematic platform-tools and build-tools versions, too, if you know them.

Comment: It seems that it doesn't work all the time. I tried to install the same versions of tools on another computer but I had the same issues. So I tried to copy/paste my Android SDK folder but nothing changed. I don't know at all why it's working on my computer right now.

Comment: It's finally working on the other computer. I'll try to list ASAP the things I did to make it work on my two computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by updating the ADT plugin and the SDK tools.

I updated my ADT from the 22.6 version to the 23.0.2 because I couldn't get the latest versions of the SDK tools.

Then, I installed :

- Android SDK Tools  rev 23.0.5
- Android SDK Platform-tools rev 21
- Android SDK Build-Tools rev 21.1.1

I also installed the Android APIs 20 and 21 but don't think that it changes anything.

Don't forget to restart eclipse and clean your workspace. I tried this on 4 computers and it worked for all of them.